# Why is my app crashing - 'NSUnknownKeyException'?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Im having an issue with Xcode where its crashing on references to old variables which I have deleted, the error message is

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
 reason: '[<mydoncaster.OptionsView 0x11fd94eb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
 this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key restaurantLabel.'
```

I don't know why its moaning about `restaurantLabel` when that no longer exist in the specific view controller, I can delete everything out of the view controller and from the storyboard and build it all again and it still brings up the error, I've also tried building and cleaning my code but it still happens, is this a saving issue or something else.

Comment: Have you tried to search for "restaurantLabel" in your storyboard? There should be an outlet somewhere in "Referencing outlets" section, which you've forgotten to delete.

Comment: Fixed it cheers, found it by right my ui switches and it was referenced to the function deleted it and it works.

Comment: Ok. This is a common mistake of mine as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "restaurantLabel" in your storyboard. 
There should be an outlet somewhere in "Referencing outlets" section, which you've forgotten to delete.